# How to provide correct country code based on country dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get a language code output based on a country dropdown.
However my output field keeps displaying wrong values.

Can you help me with this? I thought this is a more elegant way than nesting IF functions but it seems I have to go for that after all?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Phla2g8EMCiHxJjRRirqj44UIWq8B_69lvHqZYeAvjg/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your formula to

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(D5, {"USA","usa";"UK","gbd";"France","fra";"Italy","ita";"Germany","ger"}, 2, 0))
```

See if that works?

Answer (score 0):

[The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570). I suggest:

```
=LOOKUP(D5,{"France","fra";"Germany","ger";"Italy","ita";"UK","gbd";"USA","usa"})
```